# Binary Classification Dataset Distribution

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, distribution

I have a question regarding the distribution of my dataset. I have a binary classification task which I need to label. I now want to know how I should distribute the labels for optimal training / testing. The real world distribution is 9:1 negative:positive. Should the labeled distribution for the training and test set should be:

1: Training: 50:50, Test: 50:50, equal distribution

2: Training: 90:10, Test: 90:10, real world distribution

3: Training: 10:90, Test: 90:10, real world, but training on opposite

What would you suggest the distribution should be and why, or are there any other considerations?

Answer (score 1):

Without context of the problem at hand it's difficult to say.

I would look into whether you want the model to focus on true positives or true negatives. 2 simple examples being:

(1) If you're detecting cancer in patients you'd likely rather have a higher false positive rate (predicting cancer when there isn't) than not (predicting the absence of cancer when there is!). This would mean you'd lean toward 50/50 or even more balanced towards positives.

(2) If you're detecting credit fraud, you'd likely rather not lose customers by over predicting fraud and cancelling everyone's card. You may also not have the resources to respond to a high number so you'd rather model for "obvious" cases first, so you'd keep the disturbing similar.

By default, I would recommend stratified sampling (similar distributions) first, then amending for the business problem at hand.